# ObjectiveC - std::string memory issues

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory-leaks, callback, objective-c++

We are using c++ class in our ObjectiveC app (iOS7.1). At some point we need to pass huge std string object to this class.

In my objectiveC code we have a function simmilar to this:

```
static string* getString()
{    
    return new string("string") //this string could be extremely  huge (we sending JSON objects through it)
}
```

This objectiveC wrapper function is called from c++ using function pointers.

My question is - is it save to delete this string variable from c++ code?
Could this cause any memory issues? When running xcode profiler it seems there are memory related to std strings,

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You should just return a string by value, the copy will get optimized away. Or if it is always the same string, return a reference to a static string. No need for `new` really.

Comment: But this string is really huge. And in c++ code is passed through couple of methods - I want to avoid copying huge string (it can have a few MB)

Comment: As I said, the copy will be optimized away. But maybe you can post some sample code showing how you cant to use the string, and clarify whether it is always the same, or if you need to generate many different ones.

Comment: Sorry for keep asking but what I wanted to do with pointer to string jsut to save memory. Now If Im passing the value the string is copied every time as I pass it right?

Comment: It depends what you mean by passing the value.

Comment: for example having function like this: bool processString(string str) and like this bool processString(string* ptr), first case is passing the value so if I have a variable string something; and pass it as that function parameter it gets copied right?

Comment: @user3210766 You can also pass by reference if there is _really_ a memory issue with the size of this string. It avoids the need for a pointer, and still lets you pass the string around without copying it.

Comment: @user3210766 Yes, but you can also pass a reference: `bool processString(const string& s);`

Comment: ok I understand, just one question - why I need to use const ?